# Teamcity on Bitnami LAMP does not work

Tags: teamcity, bitnami

I installed a bitnami LAMP VM on azure. Then I installed JAVA JRE and Teamcity. When I start teamcity everything looks fine. but when I run `http://myurl:8111` the browser keeps connecting until I get a timeout.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?